# Pattern match None or Some with some condition

Tags: scala

Is there a syntax to achieve the following:

```
map.get(key) match {
  case None | Some(v) if v != 0 =>
    // Do something
  case _ =>
    // Do something else
}
```

So I want to do the same thing if either the map does not contain the value or the map contains the value and meets a certain condition

Answer (score 3):

You can use conditions at case sections like this:

```
value match {
  case _ if value == None || value.get != 0 => // Do something
  case _ => // Do something else
}
```

Comment: You could, but there's nothing at all gained by the match and the case there. Just use if-else.

Comment: I would probably use something like: `map.get(key).filter(_ == 0).fold(...)(v => ...)`

Comment: This particular example can be simplified to `if (map.get(key) == Some(0)) ... else ...` though.

Answer (score 0):

You could produce an intermediate value:

```
if (
    map.get(key) match {
        case None              => true
        case Some(v) if v == 0 => true
        case _                 => false
    }
) {
    // Do something
}
else {
    // Do something else
}
```